# How to formalize Elements of Statistical Learning's computation for the EPE of linear regression

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Let $X\in \mathbb R^d,Y\in \mathbb R$ be random variables. The **expected prediction error** of a predictor $f$ is

$$
\mathbb E[(f(X) - Y)]^2.
$$

Suppose the true distribution of data satisfies

- There is $\beta\in\mathbb R^d, \sigma^2\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ such that $Y\sim \mathcal N(\beta^TX, \sigma^2)$.
- $\mathbb E[X] = 0$.

Suppose we draw a sample of $N$ points from this distribution, and let $f$ be the predictor formed by linear regression.

Equation 2.28 of Elements of Statistical Learning computes the expected prediction error of $f$ as *approximately* being

$$
EPE(f)\approx \sigma^2(d/N) + \sigma^2.
$$

**Is there a way to make this more formal?**

It is only approximate because it uses $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}/N\to Cov(X)$ as $N\to\infty$, where $\mathbf{X}$ is the $N\times d$ data matrix to conclude

$$
\mathbb E [x_0^T (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1} x_0] \approx \mathbb E [x_0^T Cov(X)^{-1} x_0]/N,
$$

where $x_0$ is another observation of $X$ independent of $\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: A couple of things: I think the distribution should be N($\beta \mathbf{X},  \sigma^2)$ given the dimensions stated. The $\sigma^2(\frac{d}{N})$ term is related to what you wrote at the end but I'm not clear on where $\frac{d}{N}$ comes from. The second term is just the variance of the error term which is the expectation of squared loss.

Comment: @markleeds I'm assuming both $\beta$ and $X$ are column vectors. Note that $X$ and $\mathbf X$ are the random variable, and the matrix of sampled values, respectively. The $d/N$ is computed in Elements of Statistical Learning.

Comment: H  @extremeax5: It's not important ( the part about the dimension ) but could you provide what $\frac{d}{N}$ is.

Comment: Hi @markleeds, $d$ is the dimension of the input data, $N$ is the sample size.

Comment: I'm fairly confident there is a way -- the technical details are cumbersome though

Comment: I'm surprised that the authors wouldn't provide the specific formula ? Maybe it's in of the the references at the back of the book ?